# Vue2: Custom Directive Like v-if

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to create a custom directive like v-if so it will only render if the data being passed into the element isn't empty. For example:

```
<div v-if="!_.isEmpty(data.employer)">{{ data.employer.name }}</div>
```

This will render only if data.employer isn't empty so it won't throw a reference error. I'm trying to create a directive that will simplify this to just `v-notEmpty="data.employer"` and run the logic inside the directive but the issue is that it's doing the hook on the custom directive after the element is being rendered so it throws the reference error that employer is undefined.

Is there any way to get a custom directive to work exactly like the v-if which runs the logic before the element is actually created. This is what I had so far:

```
    Vue.directive('notEmpty', (el, binding) => {
  if (_.isEmpty(binding.value)) {
    el.style.display =  'none';
  } else {
    el.style.display =  'initial';
  }
});
```

Comment: This would generally be solved by using the slots API that Vue provides: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots

Comment: Sorry, a little confused...what would be solved by using slots? I use slots but not sure how that would solve what I'm asking. Could you provide a quick example of what you mean?

Comment: Wait...sorry, I completely misread that. My bad.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to use custom directive?

Comment: what you try to do is something like v-show directive, but  v-if is different. if condition is false, v-if won't do anything, however, v-show will stil render the element, just toogle it using css . so the expression in the double curly braces still get executed , so you got reference error.

Comment: @ShubhamPatel to make our code cleaner and standardize the way we conditionally render in our development team

Comment: @Julien yes, I know why it's not working. That's why I'm asking if there is a way to get a custom directive to work like a v-if.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the directive code inside bind hook function. ([Reference](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Hook-Functions))

**Bind**:

> called only once, when the directive is first bound to the element. This is where you can do one-time setup work.

So your code should be:

```
Vue.directive('notEmpty', {
  bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    if (_.isEmpty(binding.value)) {
      el.style.display =  'none';
    } else {
      el.style.display =  'initial';
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I've tried this :(, it's still trying to evaluate `data.employer.name` before the bind gets invoked so it still throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

Once you're using Lodash, the _.get() function may be a simpler solution. It provides a safe access to nested object proprieties. A simple example:

```js
new Vue({
    data: {
        employer: {
            name: {
              first: 'Eric',
              last: '',
            },
            age: 26
        }
    },

    methods: {
        /**
         * Check if a property exists and returns a boolean
         * 
         * @param {String} e Path to check
         * @param {Object} o Object to be accessed
         * 
         * @return {Boolean}
         */
        notEmpty(o, e) {
            let getResult = _.get(o, e);
            return !(getResult == false || getResult == null || getResult == '' || getResult == undefined);
        }
    }
}).$mount('#app');
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <p v-if="notEmpty(employer, 'name.first')">{{employer.name.first}}</p>
  <p v-else>First name not informed</p>
  
  <p v-if="notEmpty(employer, 'name.last')">{{employer.name.last}}</p>
  <p v-else>Last name not informed</p>
  
  <!-- Age will not appear, once is not defined -->
  <p v-if="notEmpty(employer, 'age')">{{employer.age}}</p>
  <p v-else>Age not informed</p>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Check out the [Lodash _.get()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get) function. It's pretty dope.